# Unexpected conversion result using QgsDistanceArea.convertLengthMeasurement

Tags: python, qgis

I am new to Python and QGIS and I am attempting to write a Python plugin for use with QGIS v3.6.0.

I am trying to convert a measurement using QgsDistanceArea().convertLengthMeasurement

I have tried to use the code in this link (scroll to Hint #2 near the end) https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog489/node/2360.

```py
qda = QgsDistanceArea()
qda.setEllipsoid('EPSG') #not sure if this is required (the project CRS is EPSG:27700)

#set input measurement
m = 1000 #not sure if the unit type needs to be set

#convert the measurement
converted = qda.convertLengthMeasurement(m, QgsUnitTypes.DistanceKilometers)

print("measure: ", m)
print("converted: ", converted)
```

I would expect the output to be:

```py
m: 1000
converted: 1
```

but the actual output is:

```py
m: 1000
converted: 111319.49079327358
```

In QGIS v2 it appears that convertLengthMeasurement requires an argument to describe the input unit type. However in QGIS v3 (the version I am using), only the output unit type is needed.

I understand that I could simply divide by 1000 to convert from meters to kilometers, but I would like to use convertLengthMeasurement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having searched further, it appears that EPSG:27700 uses WGS84 ellipsoid. "EPSG" was not a valid ellipsoidAcronym.

Adding the following line:

```py
qda.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
```

appears to make it work correctly.